# @QueryParam Retrieve Form Parameters

Tags: java, rest, kendo-ui, jersey, jax-rs

I have query parameters which are being sent from browser in the following format

```
sort[0][field]:prodId
sort[0][dir]:asc
```

How can I retrieve the above parameters in server using `@QueryParam`?

From chrome console

```
take:5
skip:0
page:1
pageSize:5
sort[0][field]:prodId
sort[0][dir]:asc
```

Comment: @peeskillet Yes, it is part of ajax query being send to server from browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@QueryParam` should be obtained from a [Query String](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) that is appended to the end of the request URL. Something like

```
http://host:port/app/something?key1=value2&key2=value2
```

You could then get `value1` and `value2` with

```
@QueryParam("key1") String value1,
@QueryParam("key2") String value2
```

Now in the title of your post, you use the word "Form". If this is form data you are trying to submit, you should consider some things. When putting the form data in the query String, this is usually done with data that is not sensitive, and used mainly for `GET` request, where the parameter values are used to help filter in getting the resource. If this is sensitive data that should be stored on the server, you generally want to `POST` the data as form data in the body of the request, as seen in the answer from [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26967672/rest-formparam-is-null)

---

**UPDATE**

If you don't know the key names, which is required to use `@QueryParam`, you can obtain the entire query string from an injected [`UriInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html). Something like

```
@GET
@Path("/path/to/resource")
public Response getKendo( @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    MultivaluedMap params = uriInfo.getQueryParameters();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object key : params.keySet()) {
        builder.append(key).append(":")
               .append(params.getFirst(key)).append("\n");
    }
    return Response.ok(builder.toString()).build();
}
```

`getQueryParameters()` will return all the keys and values in [`MultivalueMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html)

**Alternatively**, if you *know* the keys, which are shown in the URL you posted in the comment

```
test.jsp?take=5&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=5&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=prodId&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc
```

then you cause just use all those key for the `QueryParam`, i.e.

```
public Response getKendo(@QueryParam("take") int take, 
                         @QueryParam("skip") int skip,
                         @QueryParam("page") int page, 
                         @QueryParam("sort[0][field]") String field...) {
}
```

All this crazy stuff `sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D` is just how URL are encoded with special character, but JAX-RS will convert back to their rightful form, ie `"sort[0][field]"`

Comment: When `serverSorting: true` is added in grid for KendoUI, data for sorting is send in `sort[0][field]:prodId` format.

Comment: I don't know anything about Kendo, but in order to use `@QueryParam`, the key/values need to be in the query string in the URL. If that information is being sent in the body, then then you can't read it as a `QueryParam`. You need inject an entity body type into the method. Now I don't know the actual serialized format that code you're posting translates to, so I may not be able to help much further, without knowing more about that.

Comment: Do you know if that data is being passed in the query String in the URL at least?

Comment: Yes, it is in the following format `test.jsp?take=5&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=5&sort%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=prodId&sort%5B0%5D%5Bdir%5D=asc`

Comment: OK, I'll post an alternative

Comment: +1, thanks for detailed explanation and code snippet, your help is much appreciated.